# Spring integration test with PowerMockito + TestNG leads to ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, testng

I'm trying to mock a static method with **PowerMockito** in an integration test with **TestNG**, but no joy so far.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContextTest.xml"})
@DatabaseSetup("/my/project/dataset.xml")
@PrepareForTest({Calendars.class})
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class SomeIntegrationTest {

    @ObjectFactory
    public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
        return new PowerMockObjectFactory();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void init() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testOne() {
        // Mock date now
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        now.setTime(DateUtil.getDate(2014, Calendar.DECEMBER, 17));
        Calendars.CalendarMutator nowCalMut = Calendars.mutate(now);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Calendars.class);
        PowerMockito.spy(Calendars.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Calendars.now()).thenReturn(nowCalMut);
    }
}
```

This mocking mechanism works in a unit test but not in an integration test. I get the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308) at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:190)
```

According to [This page](http://www.jayway.com/2011/05/19/powermock-for-integration-testing/), you can/should use the `@PowerMockIgnore` annotation to get rid of classloaders issues. I've tried several (random) combinations (one at the time of course):

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.w3c.dom.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*"})
```

I go a bit further:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308) at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [jaxws-clients.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContextTest.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [jaxws-clients.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Class [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spring.NamespaceHandler] for namespace [http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws] does not implement the [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandler] interface
```

But that looks like a wild goose chase that goes on with freestyle variations:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.w3c.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "org.apache.*", "org.w3c.dom.*", "org.apache.cxf.*"}
```

Other [resource](http://www.jayway.com/2010/12/28/using-powermock-with-spring-integration-testing/) suggests the use of `@Rule`, but that's for JUnit if I'm not mistaken, an I'm using TestNG.

Any suggestion on how to make this work?

- powermockito 1.4.9
- spring 3.0.5
- testng 6.0.1

**EDIT 2 years later**: I'm now long retired from the project. Two years later and working with a different stack (Grails + GEB and SPOCK), mocking static data is still hard, specially in integration tests where you should probably not mock anything at all. I don't do that anymore anyway. Instead, I pass the `Date` (or `LocalDate`) as a parameter (to service methods), or simply I build the test data set to be relative to `now`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess, but I don't see any annotations of `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` being used which should help out. Also, ensure that you are using the lastest version of PowerMock, which at the time of this writing is: `1.6.6`

Comment: I think it was somewhere in an ancestor class or in an actual annotation (the original code had been cleaned up for SO posting). See my update to my original post.